# Не проходит валидацию вложенный <img> в <ul>. Как сделать код валидным, чтобы сетка на флексах не полетела?

Tags: html, css, валидация

Пытаюсь сделать на флексах сетку со списком. При этом к некоторым элементам списка представлены картинки. Визуально все работает, а валидацию пройти не могу. Подскажите, что можно сделать, чтобы флексы не поехали и валидацию код смог пройти. Спасибо. Код представлен ниже. Правильное отображение на картинке во вложении.

```css
/*Преимущества*/

.advantages-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 63px 240px 23px 240px;
}

.advantages-discription-main {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 164%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px 79px;
}

.advantages-list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
}


/*Блоки преимуществ с картинками*/
.advantages-item-picture {
    width: 400px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: #83B3D3;
   
}

.advantages-title-picture {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 98px 80px 0px;
}

.advantages-discription-picture {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 90px;
    
}

.advantages-number {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0px 26px; 
}

/*.advantages-image {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
} */

/*Блоки преимуществ без картинок*/
.advantages-subitem {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(131, 179, 211, 0.12);
    min-height: 384px;
}

/*Иконки в блоках преимуществ*/
.advantages-icon {
    margin: 89px 163px 0px;
}

.subitem-white {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.subitem-4 {
    background-color: rgba(131, 179, 211, 0.2);
}





.advantages-subitem-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 97px 0px 0px;
}

/*Название преимуществ с иконками*/
.advantages-subitem-icon{
    margin: 23px 0px 20px;
}

.advantages-subitem-discription {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 75px;
    
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages">
  <ul class="advantages-list">
    <li class="advantages-item-picture">
      <h3 class="advantages-title-picture">Настоящий городок</h3>
      <p class="advantages-discription-picture advantages-number">-№1-</p>
      <p class="advantages-discription-picture">Седона — не аттракцион для туристов, там течёт своя жизнь</p>
    </li>
    <img class="advantages-image" src="images/photo-1.jpg" alt="Гостиница на фоне гор и цветы на переднем плане">
    <li class="advantages-subitem">
      <img class="advantages-icon" src="images/icon-1.svg" alt="">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title advantages-subitem-icon">Жильё</h3>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Рекомендуем пожить в настоящем мотеле,<br> всё как в кино!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="advantages-subitem subitem-white">
      <img class="advantages-icon" src="images/icon-2.svg" alt="">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title advantages-subitem-icon">Еда</h3>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Всегда заказывайте топовый фирменный бургер, вы не разочаруетесь!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="advantages-subitem">
      <img class="advantages-icon" src="images/icon-3.svg" alt="">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title advantages-subitem-icon">Сувениры</h3>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Не только китайского, но и настоящего местного производства!</p>
    </li>
    <img src="images/photo-2.jpg" alt="Место в горах 'Мост дьявола'">
    <li class="advantages-item-picture">
      <h3 class="advantages-title-picture">Там есть мост дьявола</h3>
      <p class="advantages-discription-picture advantages-number">-№2-</p>
      <p class="advantages-discription-picture">Да, по нему можно пройти! Если вы осмелитесь, разумеется</p>
    </li>
    <li class="advantages-subitem">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title">Небольшая площадь</h3>
      <p class="advantages-number">-№3-</p>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Все достопримечательности находятся очень близко</p>
    </li>
    <li class="subitem-4 advantages-subitem ">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title">Красивая дорога</h3>
      <p class="advantages-number">-№4-</p>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Ехать в Седону из Лас-Вегаса совсем не скучно!</p>
    </li>
    <li class="advantages-subitem">
      <h3 class="advantages-subitem-title">Мало туристов</h3>
      <p class="advantages-number">-№5-</p>
      <p class="advantages-subitem-discription">Большинство едет в Гранд Каньон и толпится там</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

[image: Как пример]

Comment: О какой валидации речь? Добавьте разметку css, у вас же в основном по разметке вопрос, как я понимаю? Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав кнопку "править"

Comment: И где картинка?

Comment: Для валидного кода тег `<ul>` должен содержать в прямой видимости вложения `<li>`. Восьмая строка вашего HTML — `<img src="images/photo-1.jpg">`. Или вложите его поглубже, или же оберните его в `<li>` задайте ему персональный `class=""` и стилизуйте сколько влезет. По имеющемуся коду без CSS тяжело представить что вы хотите визуализировать.

Comment: Если вложить <img> в <li>, то нарушается семантика списка, ведь картинка относиться по факту к одному из элементов списка преимуществ, а не является отдельным преимуществом. Есть ли другие варианты, чтобы семантика осталась понятной скринридерам?

Comment: А сейчас, можно подумать, у Вас крутая "семантика" :)) Если картинка относится к элементу списка, то она должна находиться внутри этого элемента, а не болтаться где-то между.

Comment: @mctoy87 со скрином хотя бы понятнее стало, что вы пытаетесь сделать.) `> Если вложить <img> в <li>... `  1. не вижу никаких противоречий. Запиховывайте в <li> и стилизуйте. 2. С учётом размаха вашего меню,.. я бы вообще-то лучше присмотрелся к другой семантике. На кой чёрт вам эти `ul>li` и избыточность, в то время как всё это можно сверстать куда меньшими жертвами воспользовавшись `display: grid` или `display: flex` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout

Comment: @stylok спасибо за ответ. Я как раз использую  `display: flex` на `<ul>` в этом коде. А так как это список преимуществ, не вижу смысла убирать `<ul>`. Попробовал по вашему совету обернуть в `<li>` картинку - поплыла высота флекс-элементов с картинкой на 4px. все проверил - не понимаю почему так происходит.

Comment: Если повесить свойство `<display: flex>` на новый элемент `<li>` с вложенной картинкой, то эти 4px к высоте уходят и макет проходит pixel perfect. Может кто-нибудь подскажет какая логика изменения высоты в моем случае?